# Android Studio Bluetooth app (When I start the application, it crashes)

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

When I start, I get this error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bluetoothmodule2, PID: 17317
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bluetoothmodule2/com.example.bt_def.BaseActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:926)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:772)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
at com.example.bt_def.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:12)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

1. MainActivity:

```
package com.example.bluetoothmodule2

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import com.example.bt_def.BaseActivity

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        startActivity(Intent(this, BaseActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Then I have a bt_def module

2)base_Activity:

```
package com.example.bt_def

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base)
        //initRcView()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.placeHolder, DeviceListFragment()).commit()
    }
}
```

3)Bluetooth constant:

```
package com.example.bt_def

object BluetoothConstants {
    const val PREFERENCES = "main_preferences"
    const val MAC = "mac"
}
```

4. DeviceListFragment:

```
package com.example.bt_def

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.bt_def.databinding.FragmentListBinding
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar


class DeviceListFragment : Fragment(), ItemAdapter.Listener {
    private var preferences: SharedPreferences? = null
    private lateinit var itemAdapter: ItemAdapter
    private lateinit var discoveryAdapter: ItemAdapter
    private var bAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentListBinding
    private lateinit var btLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    private lateinit var pLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        preferences = activity?.getSharedPreferences(BluetoothConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        binding.imBluetoothOn.setOnClickListener {
            btLauncher.launch(Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE))
        }
        binding.imBluetoothOn.setOnClickListener {
            try {
                if(bAdapter?.isEnabled == true) {
                    bAdapter?.startDiscovery()
                    it.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.pbSearch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }catch (e: SecurityException){

            }
        }
        intentFilters()
        checkPermission()
        initRcViews()
        registerBtLauncher()
        initBtAdapter()
        bluetoothState()
    }

    private fun initRcViews() = with(binding){
        rcViewPaired.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        rcViewSearch.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(this@DeviceListFragment, false)
        discoveryAdapter = ItemAdapter(this@DeviceListFragment, true)
        rcViewPaired.adapter = itemAdapter
        rcViewPaired.adapter = discoveryAdapter
    }

    private fun getPairedDevices(){
        try {
            val list = ArrayList<ListItem>()
            val deviceList = bAdapter?.bondedDevices as Set<BluetoothDevice>
            deviceList.forEach{
                list.add(
                    ListItem(
                        it,
                        preferences?.getString(BluetoothConstants.MAC,"") == it.address
                    )
                )
            }
            binding.tvEmptyPaired.visibility = if(list.isEmpty()) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            itemAdapter.submitList(list)
        } catch (e: SecurityException){

        }

    }

    private fun initBtAdapter() {
        val bManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as
                BluetoothManager
        bAdapter = bManager.adapter
    }

    private fun bluetoothState() {
        if (bAdapter?.isEnabled == true) {
            changeButtonColor(binding.imBluetoothOn, Color.GREEN)
            getPairedDevices()
        }
    }

    private fun registerBtLauncher() {
        btLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                changeButtonColor(binding.imBluetoothOn, Color.GREEN)
                Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Блютуз включен!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Блютуз выключен!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun checkPermission(){
        if (!checkBtPermissions()){
            registerPermissionListener()
            launchBtPermission()
        }
    }

    private fun launchBtPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            pLauncher.launch(arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ))
        } else {
            pLauncher.launch(arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ))
        }
    }


    private fun registerPermissionListener(){
        pLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ){

        }
    }

    private fun saveMac(mac: String){
        val editor = preferences?.edit()
        editor?.putString(BluetoothConstants.MAC, mac)
        editor?.apply()
    }

    override fun onClick(item: ListItem) {
        saveMac(item.device.address)
    }

    private val bReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver(){
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if(intent?.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND){
                val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                val list  = mutableListOf<ListItem>()
                list.addAll(discoveryAdapter.currentList)
                if(device != null)list.add(ListItem(device, false))
                discoveryAdapter.submitList(list.toList())
                binding.tvEmptySearch.visibility = if (list.isEmpty()) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
                try{
                    Log.d("MyLog", "Device: ${device?.name}")
                } catch (e: SecurityException){

                }

        } else if(intent?.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED){
                getPairedDevices()
            }else if (intent?.action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED){
                binding.imBluetoothSearch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.pbSearch.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            }

    }

    private fun intentFilters(){
        val f1 = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        val f2 = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)
        val f3 = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
        activity?.registerReceiver(bReceiver, f1)
        activity?.registerReceiver(bReceiver, f2)
        activity?.registerReceiver(bReceiver, f3)
    }
}
```

5)Extension.kt:

```
package com.example.bt_def

import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.ImageButton
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import java.util.jar.Manifest

fun Fragment.changeButtonColor(button: ImageButton, color: Int){
    val drawable = button.drawable
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color)
    button.setImageDrawable(drawable)
}
fun Fragment.checkBtPermissions(): Boolean{
    return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }else {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

6. ItemAdapter:

```
package com.example.bt_def

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckBox
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bt_def.databinding.ListItemBinding

class ItemAdapter(private val listener: Listener, val adapterType: Boolean):
    ListAdapter<ListItem, ItemAdapter.MyHolder>(
    Comparator()
){
    private var oldCheckBox: CheckBox? = null

    class MyHolder (
        view: View, private val adapter: ItemAdapter,
        private val listener: Listener,
        val adapterType: Boolean
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val b = ListItemBinding.bind(view)
        private var item1: ListItem? = null

        init {
            b.checkBox.setOnClickListener {
                item1?.let { it1 -> listener.onClick(it1) }
                adapter.selectCheckBox(it as CheckBox)
            }
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                if (adapterType) {
                    try {
                        item1?.device?.createBond()

                    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                    }

                } else {
                    item1?.let { it1 -> listener.onClick(it1) }
                    adapter.selectCheckBox(b.checkBox)
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(item: ListItem) = with(b) {
            checkBox.visibility = if(adapterType) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
            item1 = item
            try {
                name.text = item.device.name
                mac.text = item.device.address
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {

            if (item.isChecked) adapter.selectCheckBox(checkBox)
        }
    }
    }

    class Comparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ListItem>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ListItem, newItem: ListItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ListItem, newItem: ListItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
            false)
        return MyHolder(view, this, listener, adapterType)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    fun selectCheckBox(checkBox: CheckBox){
        oldCheckBox?.isChecked = false
        oldCheckBox = checkBox
        oldCheckBox?.isChecked = true
    }

    interface  Listener{
        fun onClick(device: ListItem)
    }
}
```

7. List Item:

```
package com.example.bt_def

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice

data class ListItem(
    val device: BluetoothDevice,
    val isChecked: Boolean,
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)